# how to delete element from array in java

Tags: java

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------How do i do delete element array in java. I have done add element in array but im not sure how to remove element from the array.---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

this is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class OnlineBookStore extends Welcome {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    OnlineBookStore e1 = new OnlineBookStore();
    e1.sayWelcome();

    int option = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    
    if (option == 1) { 
        
        String pass;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the password: ");
        pass = in.nextLine();
        
        if(pass.equals("best")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome Admin. Which option would you like to choose?");
            System.out.println("1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Delete");
            System.out.println("3. Modify");
            int choice = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            
            if (choice == 1) {
                
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                
                do { 
                    System.out.println("Current list is" + list);
                    System.out.println("add (y/n)");
                    if (in.next().startsWith("y")) {
                        System.out.println("Enter:  ");
                        list.add(in.next());
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } while(true);
                in.close();
                String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
                System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
                } 
            }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong password.");
        }  
        
            
    } 
    
    
    if (option == 2) {
        
        String pass;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the password: ");
        pass = in.nextLine();
        
        if(pass.equals("bbb")) {
            System.out.println("History of sold and stock books");
            System.out.println("Sold books:");
            System.out.println("Life Without Limits");
            System.out.println("Think and Grow Rich");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Stock Books:");
            System.out.println("Lie of Pi");
            System.out.println("The Hobbit");
            
        }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong password.");
        }
    }
    if (option == 3) {
        
        String user; 
        
        System.out.println("Enter your username:  (so we know if you are a registered user.)");
        user = in.nextLine();

        if(user.equals("Ossar") || user.equals("Goala") || user.equals("Howale")) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
        }else {
            System.out.println("You are not a registered user");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete part of element in Java String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076746/delete-part-of-element-in-java-string-array)

Comment: how to remove element in java string array base on user input

Comment: i do not want delete intergers, i want delete string from the array